# How to make an union of prefetch_related from different foreign keys?

Tags: django, optimization, django-orm

I have three models, let's take an imaginary example:

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class EntityAssociation(models.Model):
    buddy1 = models.ForeignKey(Entity, related_name='+')
    buddy2 = models.ForeignKey(Entity, related_name='+')

class EntityPhoto(models.Model):
    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entity, null=True)
    association = models.ForeignKey(EntityAssociation, null=True)
    title = ...
```

We have some people (`Entity`), that can share personal photos of themselves. We also have some relations between entities (represented by `EntityAssociation`) that can also share photos of them together.

For a single entity, I can retrieve all the photo associated to an entity, either directly or through an association, doing so:

```
 obj = Entity.objects.last()
 EntityPhoto.objects.filter(
      Q(entity=obj) | Q(association__buddy1=obj) | Q(association__buddy2=obj)
 )
```

What I want is being able to **prefetch** all the photos of a set of entities selected. A typical use-case would be:

```
 for entity in Entity.objects.all().prefetch(???):
      print(entity.name, 'has', len(entity.photos_prefetched), 'photos')
      print([x.title for x in entity.photos_prefetched])
```

And this should be returning all the photos. A solution with three queries (Entity listing, prefetch through `entity`, prefetch through `association` attr ; two would be perfect) would satisfy me but the more important **is to be able to iterate through a single list**, on each entity

I tried to look the internal code of `Prefetch` but it looks like a prefetch is tied to a lookup, plus I don't know how to make the Q query in this case (what should be the right operand in `Q(entity__in=...)`?)

**Notice**: The point here is not about refactoring the database structure (`EntityAssociation` is used for a plenty of other things so it can't be reduced to a M2M of `EntityPhoto` for example.) but optimizing this specific use-case, if possible.

Comment: Did you end up with a good solution ?

Comment: @konoufo No. I'm still doing two separate prefetch to get all the photos of an Entity. However, my use case evolved so I don't really need the single merged list anymore, so I did not dig this further :-)

Answer (score -1):

I'm currently playing a bit with `Prefetch`. In my opinion it's in a pretty good shape and quite powerful.

My approach to your problem would probably be something like:

```
entities = Entity.objects.all().prefetch(Prefetch(
    'entity_photo__set',
    EntityPhoto.objects.filter(
        Q(entity=obj) | Q(association__buddy1=obj) | Q(association__buddy2=obj
    )
    to_attr="photos_prefetched",
))
```

You can then access those photos with `for entity in entities: entity.photos_prefetched`.

If this is not working, the problem might be that you're referencing back (`Q(entity=obj)`) to the actual entity. Not sure if this is properly possible. I'm having trouble with references back to the object, might be a bug in Django.